# sails doesnt not auto insert dependencies with handlebars

Tags: sails.js

I'm trying to use handlebars for the templating engine but sails does not seem to insert the files in the dependency folder.

/config/views.js:

```
engine: 'handlebars',
layout: false,
partials: false
```

/views/login.handlebars:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <!--STYLES-->
    <!--STYLES END-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Handlebars</p>
    <!--SCRIPTS-->
    <!--SCRIPTS END-->
  </body>
</html>
```

/assets/js/dependencies contains:

- bootstrap.min
- jquery.min
- sails.io.js

When I go to the rendered page after lifting sails the files are not populated in between the scripts tag.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You should update your tasks/config/sails-linker.js and replace all occurrences of ".ejs" with ".handlebars"

E.g. from:

```
devJs: {
  options: {
  startTag: '<!--SCRIPTS-->',
  endTag: '<!--SCRIPTS END-->',
  fileTmpl: '<script src="%s"></script>',
  appRoot: '.tmp/public'
  },
  files: {
    '.tmp/public/**/*.html': require('../pipeline').jsFilesToInject,
    'views/**/*.html': require('../pipeline').jsFilesToInject,
    'views/**/*.ejs': require('../pipeline').jsFilesToInject // <- HERE
  }
},
```

to

```
devJs: {
  options: {
  startTag: '<!--SCRIPTS-->',
  endTag: '<!--SCRIPTS END-->',
  fileTmpl: '<script src="%s"></script>',
  appRoot: '.tmp/public'
  },
  files: {
    '.tmp/public/**/*.html': require('../pipeline').jsFilesToInject,
    'views/**/*.html': require('../pipeline').jsFilesToInject,
    'views/**/*.handlebars': require('../pipeline').jsFilesToInject // <-HERE
  }
},
```

See also this page (where the original answer comes from).
https://mtjburton.co.uk/post/sailsjs+handlebarsjs/